# Connecting to local Mysql server from other pc

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection, ubuntu-14.04

I have an local server which installed apache and mysql servers. both of them works very well. I can display the apache default page on browser fine. And I can manage the mysql database via terminal. All okey for now. But if I try to write code to use my DB. It gives me communication link error.

Here is the simple JAVA code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.49:3306/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "1234";

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            System.out.println("Database connected!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
        }

    }
```

AND HERE IS THE ERROR:

Connecting database...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot
>   connect the database!     at
>   servermysql.ServerMysql.main(ServerMysql.java:34) Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

THE SERVER İS UBUNTU 14.04 SERVER

THANK YOU FRİENDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set MYSQL bind-address to `0.0.0.0` because it usually only listens on `127.0.0.1` by default executing following command:

```
sed -i -e”s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/” /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Or manually change the bind-address to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restart MYSQL.